# using copy in iterations

Tags: python, loops

something is not going right in my code below. I have a big for loop which handles some math. But in the for loop the following guys contribute to the end result.
say:

```
for i in range(N):
    # The math goes here. 
    sumrfactor=0.0
    for k in R_factor:
        sumrfactor += k
    # print(sumrfactor)

    Rfactor_sum=0
    for n in signal:
        Rfactor_sum +=n
    #print(Rfactor_sum)
    r_factor = sumrfactor/Rfactor_sum
    rfactor = [r_factor.copy()]

export = open('note.txt','w')
for n in rfactor:
    export.write(str(n))
```

For each iteration I want to copy r_factor I need it for some further analysis, so I am expecting to get N number of r_factor at the end of the big for loop. But for some weird reason I keep getting the final value at the end of the mighty for loop. i.e. I get one value instead of an array. Please guys I need your help with this issue, I have no idea where the problem is at. When I open the note file there is always a single figure which obviously does not look right. Thanks guys in advance!

Comment: What do you expect `rfactor = [r_factor.copy()]` to do? In particular, what do you think the effect of putting brackets around something is? It's almost certainly not doing what you think it does.

Comment: Consider using the built-in `sum` function; `sumrfactor=sum(R_factor)`. Additionally, but this is a matter of taste, you might want to think about giving your variables more distinct names. They're kind of hard to tell apart as it is.

Comment: That suppose to be an array but is does not matter anyways, I just put it there to see whether the compiler was gonna yell at me but it didn't.

Comment: Roland: I used the built in sum and the compiler didn't like it that is why I used this approach to find the sum of the array R_factor.

Comment: @user3843064 Can you show us what `R_factor` and `signal` are? Lists of numbers, lists of lists, numpy arrays? Because if they are both lists of numbers, `r_factor` will be a number, not a list! Please try to give a minimal viable example that reprduces the error.

Comment: the following:factor = signal[4:201]-inverse_truncated[4:201]

    R_factor = [i if i > 0 else -i for i in factor], that is where all this came about but I expect r_factor to be a number but it being in a loop it cannot remain a number rather it has to be an array of length N

Comment: You have a lot of problems. R_factor and signal never change, so r_factor will always have the same value. What are you trying to do at all?

Comment: They do change after each cycle, I've done it with your help I appreciate that a lot, thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't append the value to the list. Change the line `rfactor = [r_factor.copy()]` to this:

```
rfactor.append(r_factor)
```

Comment: I tried append and extend none avail Miindlek, I am not sure what is going on!

Comment: You need to define an empty list at first. Write `rfactor = []` before the first loop.

Comment: Yep thanks Miindlek that solves it. that had to be out of the mighty loop woow. Thanks again